# AWS Toolkit for Eclipse Luna 4.4.1 does not install

Tags: eclipse, amazon-web-services, installation, toolkit

I have Eclipse Luna 4.4.1. While trying to install AWS Toolkit from the url, http://aws.amazon.com/eclipse or from Eclipse marketplace url https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/aws-toolkit-eclipse#group-external-install-button (using drag and drop button), following error happens,

```
Unable to read repository at http://aws.amazon.com/eclipse/site.xml/content.xml.
Unable to read repository at http://aws.amazon.com/eclipse/site.xml/content.xml.
peer not authenticated
```

Sometimes it lists down the components available for install but everytime it fails with above error. One thing I noticed is content.xml urls does not seem to be valid or are being interpreted as a invalid URL.

Request help.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

An incorrect URL is specified for the Eclipse Marketplace item *AWS Toolkit for Eclipse* (the URL should not end with `site.xml`).

Instead of using drag and drop, you have to use ***Help > Install*** with the correct URL **`http://aws.amazon.com/eclipse/`**